# User computer won't run exes and internet Explorer unless run as admin

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, administrator

I am having a problem with a computer running Windows 7 on our domain. This computer will not run internet Explorer correctly, for example using citrix addon.

Also when I tried installing `.exe`'s they would give an error 2349. Another thing is when I download an exe from Internet Explorer 9, they would be .exe but cannot be run and not shown as executable but as file. If I run exes as Administrator or internet Explorer as Administrator, they work as intended. Any ideas?

Comment: Open Registry Editor as that user and check whether `HKCU\Software\Classes\.exe` and `HKCU\Software\Classes\exefile` exist; if yes, delete them. (Be careful -- don't confuse it with the system-wide `HKLM\Software\Classes`.)

Comment: "This computer will not run internet explorer correctly, for example using citrix add-on" Can you please give us some details on what doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there are some good security restrictions in place.  This may be expected security behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with uSlackr, it sounds as if Windows is (correctly) configured so that non-Admin users can't install software or run untrusted (downloaded) binaries. Again, this is *correct* behavior, not a problem. You should install software only as Admin, and only after taking due care.